# Ember.js- define a global function that can return a value to actions

Tags: javascript, ember.js

The code below shows a standard JavaScript pattern for defining a function that takes a number of bytes and converts it into a readable format.

In standard JavaScript, you can call the function as a variable, so that the variable value is whatever the function returns.

```js
//Define function
function bytesToReadable(numberOfBytes) {
  var readableSize;
  var units;
  if (numberOfBytes <= 1000) {
    readableSize = numberOfBytes;
    units = ' bytes';
  } else if (numberOfBytes > 1000 && numberOfBytes <= 1000000) {
    readableSize = Math.ceil(numberOfBytes / 1000);
    units = ' KB';
  } else if (numberOfBytes > 1000000 && numberOfBytes <= 1000000000) {
    readableSize = (numberOfBytes / 1000000).toFixed(2);
    units = ' MB';
  } else if (numberOfBytes > 1000000000 && numberOfBytes <= 1000000000000) {
    readableSize = Math.ceil(numberOfBytes / 1000000000);
    units = ' GB';
  }
  var prettySize = readableSize + units;
  return prettySize;
}
//Call function
var test = bytesToReadable(2360000);
console.log(test);//Logs '2.36MB'
```

What is the correct way of achieving this type of pattern in Ember?

I have tried placing the code in it's own action as below, but this returns undefined:

---

```js
actions: {
  bytesToReadable: function(numberOfBytes) {
    var readableSize;
    var units;
    if (numberOfBytes <= 1000) {
      readableSize = numberOfBytes;
      units = ' bytes';
    } else if (numberOfBytes > 1000 && numberOfBytes <= 1000000) {
      readableSize = Math.ceil(numberOfBytes / 1000);
      units = ' KB';
    } else if (numberOfBytes > 1000000 && numberOfBytes <= 1000000000) {
      readableSize = (numberOfBytes / 1000000).toFixed(2);
      units = ' MB';
    } else if (numberOfBytes > 1000000000 && numberOfBytes <= 1000000000000) {
      readableSize = Math.ceil(numberOfBytes / 1000000000);
      units = ' GB';
    }
    var prettySize = readableSize + units;
    return prettySize;
  },

  anotherAction: function() {
    var test = this.send('bytesToReadable', 2360000);
    console.log(test) //Logs undefined.
  },
}
```

I have also tried using properties:

```js
bytesToReadable: function(numberOfBytes) {
    var readableSize;
    var units;
    if (numberOfBytes <= 1000) {
      readableSize = numberOfBytes;
      units = ' bytes';
    } else if (numberOfBytes > 1000 && numberOfBytes <= 1000000) {
      readableSize = Math.ceil(numberOfBytes / 1000);
      units = ' KB';
    } else if (numberOfBytes > 1000000 && numberOfBytes <= 1000000000) {
      readableSize = (numberOfBytes / 1000000).toFixed(2);
      units = ' MB';
    } else if (numberOfBytes > 1000000000 && numberOfBytes <= 1000000000000) {
      readableSize = Math.ceil(numberOfBytes / 1000000000);
      units = ' GB';
    }
    var prettySize = readableSize + units;
    return prettySize;
  },
  actions: {
    anotherAction: function() {
      var test = this.get('bytesToReadable', 2360000);
      console.log(test);//Logs the function itself.
    },
  }
```

I would like to be able to run this code from various different parts of my application. What is the best way to make such a function available throughout my app, so that it can return the result to the function it has been called from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to deal with this would be to create a utility function, running `ember g util bytesToReadable` will generate the boilerplate, what is left is to move your code to the file:

```
export default function bytesToReadable(numberOfBytes) {
  let readableSize;
  let units;
  if (numberOfBytes <= 1000) {
    readableSize = numberOfBytes;
    units = ' bytes';
  } else if (numberOfBytes > 1000 && numberOfBytes <= 1000000) {
    readableSize = Math.ceil(numberOfBytes / 1000);
    units = ' KB';
  } else if (numberOfBytes > 1000000 && numberOfBytes <= 1000000000) {
    readableSize = (numberOfBytes / 1000000).toFixed(2);
    units = ' MB';
  } else if (numberOfBytes > 1000000000 && numberOfBytes <= 1000000000000) {
    readableSize = Math.ceil(numberOfBytes / 1000000000);
    units = ' GB';
  }
  let prettySize = readableSize + units;
  return prettySize;
}
```

And when you want to use it in the app you would `import bytesToReadable from 'yourAppName/utils/bytes-to-readable'`.

Comment: On a sidenote, this looks like a presentation concern, a helper might be more suitable for it.

Comment: Also `bytes` should be handled as component property and `bytesToReadable` should be a computed property using your utility function. Unless it's a presentation concern. As @Kitler a template helper should be used in these case.

Comment: Thanks for an excellent answer. I tried the above and it worked perfectly with `var test =  bytesToReadable(2360000);` - the variable `test` is '2.36MB'.

However, I have taken your advice and implemented this as a component, as it is just a presentation concern. Thanks for the advice :).

Comment: @AJP Give [Ember.Helper](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Helper.html)` a look as well

Comment: Ok- I have now changed the component to a helper. I can see how this is far preferable as you don't need a .hbs file for the helper as yo do with a component. Many thanks.